# Fetching random data from a particular row

Tags: sql, mysql, select, subquery

Suppose, I have created a table XYZ containing row 'Age' having values (10, 24, 6, 41, 27, 11). Now, if I put 6 in the query, I want to fetch all the values from that row 'Age' which are coming after 6.

| Age |
| --- |
| 10 , 24, 6, 41, 27, 11 |

Chosen Value: 6

Expected Output: 41 , 27 , 11.

Any query like this?

Comment: How many rows and columns your table has?

Comment: I assume you mean the table has a _column_ age? Never store age, people become older every year and your data will soon be out-of-date. Store date of birth instead.

Answer (score 1):

If your table has one column and six rows, there's no way to approach this problem deterministically, because rows of a DBMS have no order, unless you first specify a subquery with an `ORDER BY` clause (explicit ordering).

If your table has one row and one column, and your values are stored as a string of comma-separated value, you can use:

- [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to split your string and get the last part only
- [`TRIM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_trim) to remove further non-required characters

```
SET @chosen_value := 6;

SELECT TRIM(LEADING ', ' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(age, @chosen_value, -1)) AS output
FROM tab
```

**Output** (for @chosen_value = 6):

| output |
| --- |
| 41, 27, 11 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dyf4s6dArA4tpPYcwzKFED/1).

Comment: I thought that values are stored in separate rows, it seems that I miss reading the question.

Comment: Rows can't have a name in sql, my guess was that OP has misnamed "*row*" for "*column*", that's why I posted this answer.